# A problem on general eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, generalized-eigenvector

Suppose T$\in$$\mathcal{L}$(V),dim(V) ＝n.$λ_{i}$ and $λ_{k}$ are two different eigenvalues of T, $v_{i}$$\not=0$ is an general eigenvetor of T corresponding to $λ_{i}$,prove whether $(T-λ_{i}I)^{n}$$(T-λ_{k}I)^{n}$$v_{i}$＝0?.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(T-λ_{i}I)^{n}(T-λ_{k}I)^{n}v_i=(T-λ_{k}I)^{n}(T-λ_{k}I)^{n}v_i=0,$ since $(T-λ_{i}I)^{n}$ and $(T-λ_{k}I)^{n}$ commute.